# Validar definição de namespace

Tags: php, validação, namespace, regex

As variáveis do PHP, caso seja necessário, podem ser validadas com a seguinte Expressão Regular:

```
[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*
```

Mas e quanto aos *namespaces*?

Tenho uma determinada string, vinda de um formulário, que servirá como nome de um diretório o qual conterá classes com *namespaces*.

Tomemos como exemplo [essa Aplicação](https://github.com/brunoaugusto/dovahkiin) plenamente funcional que uso como *playground* de testes, cuja parte da estrutura de diretórios, a partir do diretório raiz, é:

```
|-\application
| \-\application\dovahkiin
|   |-\application\dovahkiin\application.php
```

A expressão a ser validada nesse caso seria a palavra **dovahkiin**.

E como quero manter o processo de *autoloading* simples, isto é, apenas substituindo o T_NS_SEPARATOR () pelo DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR do sistema operacional e, por fim, concatenando a extensão do arquivo ([assim](https://github.com/nextframework/next/blob/dev/Loader/AutoLoader/Stream.php#L27)), preciso que essa string seja válida como parte de um *namespace*.

Eu já sei que characteres não alfa-numéricos, como pontos e espaços, são inválidos, mas não tenho certeza se a mesma Expressão  Regular usada para variáveis seria válida para namespaces também.

Comment: não consegui compreender bem sua pergunta, poderia fornecer dados de `namespaces` que você considera valido?
Quanto a expressão `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]`. `\x7f`, pela tabela acsii é o `delete`, ainda assim, você esta indo ate o `\xff` ou seja, permitindo estes caracteres : `ƒ,«,╣`.
Se você esta falando de validar a escreta da variável e não  seu conteúdo, seria isto? `^(\$?[a-zA-Z_]\w*)$`

Comment: O motivo principal de querer validar um namespace é justamente porque ele pode ser desconhecido. Quando **eu** defino meus namespaces, uso estritamente letras, mas para validação, pode ser que outros caracteres também sejam válidos. Quando a essa Expressão Regular, não fui eu quem criou. Eu apenas copiei [do manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)